# Django/python: How to use two name spaces in a a single url in Django?

Tags: django, namespaces, django-urls

I created a Django project where a parent have a list of child. I wanted to show the detail of a child with url as - /parent/4/child/3. How can I define two namespaces in a single url? Can Someone explain how can i achieve this or suggest some example!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to show the detail of a child with url as - /parent/4/child/3. How can I define two namespaces in a single url?

It seems like you want to define a URL that takes two integers (id's) and maps them to keywords.

```
url(r'^foo/(?P<foo_id>[0-9]+)/bar/(?P<bar_id>[0-9]+)/$', foo_bar_view),
```

The above url pattern will give you two different integer key, value pairs.
`foo_id` as well as `bar_id`.

Here's what `foo_bar_view` might look like.

```
def foo_bar_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    foo_id = kwargs["foo_id"]
    bar_id = kwargs["bar_id"]
    return HttpResponse(
        "foo_id: {0} -- bar_id: {1}".format(
            foo_id=foo_id,
            bar_id=bar_id,
        )
    )
```

If that was your view function and you made a request to a url like the following.

`/foo/12/bar/34/`

Then your page will receive an httpresponse of:

`foo_id: 12 -- bar_id: 34`